# Eclipse Color Theme Plugin - Unable to read repository

Tags: eclipse, plugins, equinox

I've tried to install the Eclipse Color Theme plugin both via the "Install New Software..." with http://eclipse-color-theme.github.io/update/ and via the Eclipse Marketplace, and also click and drag from the Marketplace website. All has failed.

I do work behind a firewall; however, I have installed m2e from the Marketplace store so I'm fairly certain it's an issue with either the plugin or my install (Kepler v. 4.3).

Here are the errors I am getting:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository 2 0 2014-03-11 17:14:47.701
!MESSAGE Server returned lastModified <= 0 for http://eclipse-color-theme.github.io/update/content.jar

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository 2 0 2014-03-11 17:14:50.145
!MESSAGE Server returned lastModified <= 0 for http://eclipse-color-theme.github.io/update/artifacts.jar

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 4 0 2014-03-11 17:14:50.993
!MESSAGE Provisioning exception
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unable to read repository at http://eclipse-color-theme.github.io/update/.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.basicRefreshRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.refreshRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.RepositoryManipulationPage$21.run(RepositoryManipulationPage.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid repository location: http://eclipse-color-theme.github.io/update/.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:102)
    ... 8 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 1002 2014-03-11 17:14:50.993
!MESSAGE Unable to read repository at http://eclipse-color-theme.github.io/update/.
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Invalid repository location: http://eclipse-color-theme.github.io/update/.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.basicRefreshRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.refreshRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.RepositoryManipulationPage$21.run(RepositoryManipulationPage.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think the `Server returned lastModified <= 0` is what is upsetting p2, something in the path to the server is returning an invalid response.

Comment: I also tried downgrading to 4.2 (which Eclipse Color Plugin says is supported) with similar results.